# How to display different contents types(twitter, imges, blog etc.) in Viewslide show in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, panel, drupal-views

I am trying to display different content types on Drupal as views slideshow, including twitter, images, and blogs. Currently they are all saved in a field (unlimited value fields). I am going to extract these values to nodes as views only accepts node type values. I am wondering what is the best way to do it? I am new to drupal and can think of following ideas:
1. Use one node type, and create a display mode for this node type with customized codes
2. A separate node type for different content types, and each node type with some display mode
3. A minipanel for each node type,is it possible to display it in view slideshow?
4. some code to get data directly from fields, and export to views?
5. Or I use Colorbox and completely forget about View Slideshow?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must set all the content types you want to pull in the query in the "edit" form of the view. It is not possible using only the one-step setup, you must choose "continue & edit" and then add different content types to your slideshow view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I see in Views setttings,under format|show, there is options to select rendered entity or content, and then there is options to select row style, with view mode corresponding to display mode? If I use this option and set up filters to limit node types, is this the right way to do it? Thanks again.

Comment: @user9319 Probably you should try and tell us what you found, if it worked or not, and in case it doesnt work, what you got using this approach and how it differs from what you need :)

Comment: Sure I will. I am working on it now and will share my results. Actually I am quite confused about Drupal theming system. There are people told me to use panel instead of theme, and I am also confused with Panel node and Display mode. Anyway, this is a good learning process and what I have learned could save others' time.

Comment: I meant that before asking a second question you should tell us how far the first answer drove you :D Anyway, keep on rockin... Drupal's learning curve is high, but then the system really deserves that effort :)

Comment: I think I have found one way to do it: Display Suite.  1. use Display Suite to create a view mode: say it's called "featuredview", and all node types to be displayed have this view mode. 2. Generate View Mode code for each node type. To save time, I use code field with Display Suite Code. (It would be best if PHP Snippet can be used for customer field, but I am not sure if there is security hole, will do more research). 3. Generate a View by view Mode. Another finding, Display Suite is good for node display, and Panel is good for page management, and the two can be used together.